# Angular application deployed to AWS lambda gives internal server error

Tags: angular, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-iam-policy

[image]I've deployed angular application to aws lambda getting deployed successfully and getting
url ( example-aws-url.amazonaws.com/production)
This is giving error

{
"message": "Internal server error"
}

Given roles are shown in image
even not able to see logs.

I am expecting angular application to be up in aws lambda.

Comment: Are you able to see the Lambda logs in CloudWatch? Internal Server Error suggests that there's an unhandled exception somewhere in your code running in Lambda function